# Skype won't detect microphone input

Tags: windows-7, audio, skype, microphone

My microphone is properly plugged in, Windows detects audio input from it, it is the default device and the green bar jiggles in "Sound Options → Recording Devices" when I speak and can record audio and play it back.

Skype, however, does not detect any input from my microphone.
For some reason I have several recording devices listed in "Sound Options" and in Skype. I tried changing the "Microphone" in Skype Options to each of them, but none detected input. Then I outright disabled those devices I know I don't use (my microphone was listed twice, for some reason with) that didn't help and cycling through microphones in Skype after that didn't, either.

Restarted the computer after these changes, didn't help.

Adding screenshots (I hope you won't mind them being in Bulgarian):
[image: Skype Audio Devices]
[image: Recording Devices 1]
[image: Recording Devices 2]
[image: Recording Devices 3]

Comment: Ive had this problem before with a load of machines on skype for buisness , i found the best way to fix it was simply to uninstall and reinstall.

Comment: @Englishman, that doesn't help.

Comment: @VanagaS, no other applications are started when issue occurs. Skype has been restarted, computer has been restarted and Skype started right away, before any other programs. Issue persists.

Comment: @VanagaS, the advanced options don't offer anything else of value for this problem, like I said I tried changing the microphone in Skype to each one to no avail and I forgot to add that the correct microphone is set as the default device in the Sound Options, just updated question.

Comment: A screenshot with the imput sound devices may help. There may be a device that's actually the mic but does not show in the list (for various reasons).

Comment: @Overmind, done did did it

Comment: The C-media PCI one may be the real mic. The HD one may be from the video card audio output. Anyway, enabling all 3 of them (this +2 HD ones) should let you determine what's what.

Comment: @Overmind, like I already said - I tried them all, no effect on either.